# How to pass model in Nested routes - emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I have some nested routes.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("dashboard", { path: "/dashboard" });
  this.resource("customers", { path: "/customers" },function(){
    this.resource("customer",{ path: "/:customer_id" },function(){
      this.resource("customer.contact",{path:'/contact'});
    });   
  });   
});
```

**TEMPLATES**

**customers/index**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customers/index">
    <h3>Customers</h3>
    <table>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        {{#link-to "customer" item tagName="td"}}Info{{/link-to}}
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </table>
  </script>
```

**customer**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customer">
    <h3>Customer {{name}}</h3>
    {{#link-to}}Gallery{{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to "customer.contact" this}}Contact{{/link-to}}
    {{outlet}}
  </script>
```

**contact**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customer/contact">
    <h3>Contact info of customer {{name}}</h3>
    {{contact}}   
  </script>
```

Go Customers->Info
Everything works fine, the link from "customers/index" template passes the item to the customer template where {{name}} will be used. but if i want to pass the context to "contact" template, it doesnt work.

here is the JsBin
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EveQOke/107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a route for customer contact (as well for customer).  The reason it works initially is because the link-to is passing the model to the route, so it can skip the non-existent model hook.  But when you refresh the page, or hit the contact route, which has no dynamic segment, you need to tell ember that you want to use a model.  There is a beta feature that allows all the routes under a resource to use the resource if they don't have another resource defined, but that's still a feature, and isn't yet gold.

```
App.CustomerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(param){
    return this.store.find('customer', param.customer_id);
  }
});

App.CustomerContactRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.modelFor('customer');
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/110/edit

Comment: thank you. very well explained. do you have a link to that BETA version?

Comment: Grab any beta build past 1.5 (http://emberjs.com/builds/#/beta ) It was added as a feature in 1.5 [FEATURE ember-routing-inherits-parent-model]

Comment: You can read more about enabling feature here http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/feature-flags/

Comment: i have tried to update the JsBin example to 1.5.1 stable version but it breaks it: http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/138